# document object of window.open

Tags: javascript

```
var theNewWindow = window.open('http://www.example.com', 'example', '');
```

How can I use the `document` object of `theNewWindow` to dynamically update the dom of the new window.

Comment: You won't be able to manipulate the DOM of a site in another domain, regardless of how you open it. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: I read something a really long time ago about using setinterval when opening a new window. I mean probably back in the nineties. It's almost certainly not possible as it would open serious security holes.

Comment: what if both parent and child windows share the same domain and protocols and ports ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, only if the new page is the same domain or about:blank. For example:

```
var temp = window.open('about:blank', 'example', '');
var div = temp.document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "Hello!";
temp.document.body.appendChild( div );
```

And [see the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/orlleite/fSpXK/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have permission to modify the new window (e.g. it's the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)), then you can get the document via:

```
theNewWindow.document
```