# How to add script files in child window using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to add script files in child window using javascript?

Consider the following code:

```
myWindow = window.open("", "", 'width=650,height=700,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.document.write('<script src="'+App.data.assets_url+'\/javascript\/jquery.js"><\/script>');
```

Above code doesn't work properly in IE. It shows blank (child) window, but in chrome it works properly. It shows all the content of the child window.

In Mozilla it's not working properly too because of above `myWindow.document.write` line browser's print option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [document object of window.open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271864/document-object-of-window-open)

Comment: Please respond and/or mark some answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Basically:

```
var win, doc;

win = window.open('', 'dialog', opts);
doc = win.document;

doc.write(
    "<html><head>"
    + "<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/your/script.js'></script>"
    + "<script type='text/javascript'>"
    + "/* this is inline script inserted by JavaScript, below is a function converted to it's string representation */"
    + someFuncInVariable.toString()
    + "</script>"
    + "</head><body>"
    + "</body></html>"
);
doc.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you don't have domain crossing, you may simply do this (using jquery) :

```
$(childwindow.document.body).append('<script src="..."></script>');
```

But a more detailed question might enable more on topic answers.

Comment: Ahh, jQuery. Ye ol pal of mine. You are so overworked, underappreciated, oversold. Why not just a plain Javascript method? Oh *my*, heaven's to betsy.

Comment: Because I don't want to spend time looking for the plain js way to do it as long as the question isn't a little more precise...