# Draw google chart in new browse window using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=500,height=500,top=200,left=200');
var doc = myWindow.document;
doc.write("<body><div id='detaildata'><body>");
var table = new google.visualization.Table(doc.getElementById('detaildata'));
table.draw(data, {
                    title: "Bug Details",
                    width: 500,
                    height: 400,
                    hAxis: { title: "Daily" }
                });
doc.close();
```

I am opening a new window from javascript. Writing a div to it. Then drawing a google chart table onto it. But table is not coming as google table. It is coming as a simple table with no styling.
How to get proper google table in the new window.

Comment: You need to append the js-scripts to the new window. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946800/how-to-add-script-files-in-child-window-using-javascript

Comment: I tried this but didn't helped.`var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.type = "text/javascript";
                    script.src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js';
                    doc.write(script.outerHTML);
                    doc.write("<script>google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart','table'] });"+"<\/script>");`

Comment: Look at jkrcma answer in the link I shared. Try it that way

Comment: it has lots of errors. My way also script is getting written. but google chart does not work.

Comment: @WhiteHat , can you give some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the new window needs access to the loader script in order to display properly

instead of opening a blank window and writing everything to it,

save a static html file, with the code you would write, already there.

example, save the following snippet to an html file,
in the same folder as the code running now

**testGoogleNW.html** (this will be the new window)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
      google.charts.load('current', {
        callback: function () {
          var container = document.getElementById('detaildata');
          var table = new google.visualization.Table(container);

          // use data from opening page
          table.draw(window.opener.data, {
            title: 'Details'
          });
        },
        packages: ['table']
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      div {
        padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="detaildata"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**calling window**
in the code you have now, use the following snippet to prepare the `data` and open the window

once the window is opened, it will take over from there

`data` here needs to be available via global scope,
the new window uses `window.opener` to get the `data` from this page

```
var data;

google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['table']
});

function drawChart() {
  data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['2013', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['2014', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['2015', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['2016', 1030, 540, 350]
  ]);

  // open static html file
  window.open('testGoogleNW.html', '', 'width=500,height=500,top=200,left=200');
}
```

you could also use `localStorage` to pass the variable

Comment: can you explain how to pass data using localstorage

Comment: i am not able to pass datatable value. Getting error = You called the draw() method with a String rather than a DataTable or DataView

Comment: just saw your comments, still having trouble? or problem with table options?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var options =
       {
           backgroundColor: '#E0E0E0',
           width: '100%',
           height: '100%',
           alternatingRowStyle: false,
       };
```

But options are not getting applied to the table. any changes required.