# How do I edit the html in a popup window?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

SO, I know how to create a popup window in google, and I know how to write in the popup window, but how do I put in other HTML tags in a popup window?

The Html code that I have is below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open("","","width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>NEW WINDOW<p>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onmousedown='openWin();'>Hello</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, in the document.write function, I have two `<p>` tags, and I can also use the `<button>` tag, but I cannot use the `<script>` tag, does anyone know why, or if it is possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946800/how-to-add-script-files-in-child-window-using-javascript

Comment: I feel like  something crucial we are missing is _why_ are you trying to write a script tag into your pop-up window?  I'm having a hard time imagining a scenario in which that would be required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to write a `<script>` tag to your popup window? You have to do it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open("","","width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.open();
myWindow.document.write("<p>NEW WINDOW<p>");
myWindow.document.write("<scr" + "ipt>alert('Script works!')</scr"+"ipt>");
myWindow.document.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onmousedown='openWin();'>Hello</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise the parent window will think the script tags are something it should interpret.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and then tell you what I think.

Comment: For some reason, when I try to make a function the program does not work. For testing purposes, I am trying to recreate the first page onto the popup.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot write "<script>" or "</script>" to the window, these are specifically disallowed. You have to split up these terms.

```
function openWin() {
    myWindow=window.open("","","width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>NEW WINDOW<p>");
    myWindow.document.write("<scr");
    myWindow.document.write("ipt>alert('Script works!')</scr")
    myWindow.document.write("ipt>");
 }
```

Comment: Way to copy my answer as your own.